# Connect to MySQL on a server

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have installed MySQL on our local server; `BUSINESS.local` and I am now trying to connect to it from a different IP.

I set this up once before using the MySQL Workbench because I was having issues connecting to it when it was installed on a different user, using the wildcard `%`. However now I can't remember how I did it.

I am using the connection string

```
server=BUSINESS.local;Uid=root;Pwd=pwd;
```

but when I connect, it returns the MySQL error:

> 1130 - Host 'Computer' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Is this the same thing? I.e. Is this error being caused because I haven't allowed the 'Computer' IP to connect to the Server's MySQL?

How do I overcome this?

P.S. If you could provide a Workbench solution as well/instead of a Command Line solution that would be great :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use localhost as your host or ip address of the remote server and try again.

Comment: I changed the IP address on the server to localhost, got the same error. I then added `server=BUSINESS.local\localhost` and got the error "Unable to connect to any specified MySQL Hosts" can I use the `\localhost` extension somehow?

Comment: you can't connect remote mysql server in your local machine but you can use remote server files and database simply sharing "xampp" folder and try to remote URL http://<ip-address>/phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

I found the option I was looking for to allow the use of the wildcard `%` or to allow certain IP addresses to connect.

In the Workbench, after connecting to a Database, you can open the "Users and Privileges" tab from the side bar or from the "Server" drop down menu. Here you can edit current user information, or add new user connections.

Specifically, in the "Limit Connectivity to Hosts Matching:" option, you can use the wildcards `%` (a substitute for zero or more characters) or `_` (a substitute for a single character).

[image]